# What is the image of the following mapping for $|w|\leq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function
$$z(w)=i \frac{w-1}{w+1} $$
How can I describe the image of $|w|\leq 1$ under this mapping?

Well I can observe that 
$$z(w)=i\frac{w\bar w-\bar w}{w \bar w +\bar w}=\bar z(w)$$
if $|w|=1$. So the boundary gets mapped to the real axis.

Also $$|z(w)|=\frac{|w-1|}{|w+1|}\leq \frac{|w|+1}{|w|+1}=1$$
So the circle will get mapped back onto itself.

Is there anything further I can say about the mapping? My complex analysis  is fairly limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final argument is wrong. You can certainly say that
$$
|z(w)|=\frac{|w-1|}{|w+1|}\le\frac{|w|+1}{|w+1|}\le\frac{2}{|w+1|}
$$
but you stop here: dividing by a larger number yields a smaller one.

Note that $w=-1$ is not allowed; suppose $|w|=1$ and write $w=e^{2i\varphi}$. Then
$$
z(w)=i\frac{e^{2i\varphi}-1}{e^{2i\varphi}+1}=
i\frac{e^{i\varphi}}{e^{i\varphi}}\frac{e^{i\varphi}-e^{-i\varphi}}{e^{i\varphi}+e^{-i\varphi}}=
i\frac{2i\sin\varphi}{2\cos\varphi}=-2\tan\varphi
$$
which approaches infinity along the real axis when $\varphi\to\pi/2$ (that is, $w$ approaches $-1$ along the circle).

Thus the range of the function is certainly unbounded and it contains the whole real line.

The inverse function is
$$
w=\frac{i+z}{i-z}
$$
Writing $z=r(\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi)$, it's easy to show that
$$
|i+z|^2=1+2r\sin\varphi+r^2,\qquad |1-z|^2=1-2r\sin\varphi+r^2
$$
so we have $|w|\le1$ if and only if
$$
r\sin\varphi\le0
$$
that is, $r=0$ or $\sin\varphi\le0$. The range is the entire lower half-plane (including the real axis).

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{Im}\bigl(i\frac {w-1}{w+1}\bigr)=\operatorname{Im}\frac {i(w-1)(\overline {w} +1)} {|w+1|^{2}}=\frac {|w|^{2}-1} {|w+1|^{2}} <0$. So every point in the image has negative imaginary part. Conversely, given any $\zeta$ with $\operatorname{Im}\zeta <0$, take $w=\frac {i+\zeta} {i-\zeta}$ and verify that the image of $w$ is $\zeta$. Hence the image is exactly the lower half of plane.

Answer (score 1):

If you know already something about [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) you need only two things:

- Find the image of $|w|=1$ using only $3$ points, since such a transformation maps generalized circles (lines and circles) onto generalized circles:

$$z(1) = 0, z(-1)= \infty, z(i) = -1 $$.

The $3$ points $0,-1,\infty$ determine a generalized circle going through $\infty$. Hence, the real axis is the image of the circle and, hence, this axis is the boundary of the image of the whole circle.

- To find where $|w| <1$ is mapped onto, just choose one point within the circle:
  $$z(0) = -i$$

$-i$ lies in the lower half plane. Hence, the inner of the circle $|w|\leq 1$ is mapped onto the lower half plane.

So, the image is the lower half plane including the real axis.

Comment: How are you able to conclude that the interior is always below based on where 0 maps to?

Comment: This is a property of the transformation. These transformations are continuous mappings of the Riemann sphere (or the compactified $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$) onto itself. So, the inner of the circle (a simply connected open set) is mapped onto one side of the image of the boundary hence onto the upper or the lower half plane.